# Changing part of navbar color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `navbar` which is designed in `Bootstrap 4` , I am trying to change the hamburger `background-color` of the navbar, and the rest of the navbar in some other color.

Here is the sketch of my current output and what I am trying to do:

[image]

I tried using z-index property but nothing seems to work. Can you give me any ideas?

```css
.navbar {
    padding-left: 80px;
    height: 54px;
    top: 40px;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    display: inline-flex;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
    border-top-right-radius: 200px;
    background-color: #A6ACAF !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light animated fadeInLeft" style="background-color: #C0C0C0 ;">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="lines"></span>
    <span class="lines"></span>
    <span class="lines"></span>
  </button> 
<h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0 move-header">NavBrand</h1>
  <div class="collapse animated fadeInLeft" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">@yield('setActive') </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please create a complete, verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you want to change the hamburger background-color try applying the style on `.navbar-toggler` class and not `.navbar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the hamburger `background-color` try applying the style on `.navbar-toggler` or `.navbar-toggler-left` class and **not** `.navbar`

```
.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**Updated:**

Left of the button is still grey - has nothing to do with the `background-color`. Bootstrap by default has the following styles on `.navbar-toggler-left`

```
.navbar-toggler-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1rem; //this is getting that left gap
}
```

Override the above `left: 1rem;` to your own value which is 0

```
.navbar-toggler {
  background-color: red;
  left: 0; //fix
}
```

Adjust `width` & `height` of the toggler accordingly if you want.

Comment: already tried. it leaves some the left part next to the button in grey color

Comment: Yeah that has nothing to do with the `background-color`... that's because bootstrap by default positions the `.navbar-toggler-left` as `absolute` & gives a left value of `left: 1rem;`. Override it to `left: 0`. Answer updated.

Comment: saved my day. I was unaware of the bootstrap adding the rem value. Thanks bud :)